# command line combine pdfs through php exec

Tags: php, pdf

I just setup wkhtmltopdf to take html docs and turn them into pdfs but now I need a way to combine the multiple pdfs.

Any suggestions?

We do have pdflib license if there is something it can do but seems its mainly an api for custom building pdfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got `wkhtmltopdf` I suppose you're using *Linux* and you got a root shell access.

You could use [Pdftk Toolkit](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) via `system()` or `exec()`.

First install it. It's a package in **Debian/Ubuntu**, for example:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Then make sure that's visible in your bin search PATH.

And a simple PHP snippet:

```
// In / Out filenames
$input_files = array( 'file_one.pdf', 'file_two.pdf' );
$file_out = 'merged.pdf';

// Escape names and create argument
$line_parts = '';
foreach( $input_files as $file ) {
     $line_parts .= escapeshellarg( $file ) . ' ';
}

// Run pdftk
$cmd = 'pdftk ' . $line_parts . ' cat output ' . escapeshellarg( $file_out );
system( $cmd, $retval );
if( $retval ) { print 'There was an error!'; }
```